# How do I hide the text cursor in wx.TextCtrl?

Tags: wxwidgets, wxtextctrl

I'm using TextCtrl in wxPython to display text read-only:

```py
control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)
```

However, the text cursor is still there, blinking.

Can I somehow hide that cursor (not the mouse pointer)?

Comment: you should disable the control. Check `wxWindw` documentation for proper flag.

Answer (score 0):

The caret is always shown in the text controls because it's useful even when they're read-only because it allows selecting and copying text from them. If you don't need this functionality, simply use `wxStaticText` instead.